# Ctrl+F2 no longer opens the app launcher in Gnome 2

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint

In KDE I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and the app launcher opens. In Gnome, however, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, it doesn't work. When I first installed Mint 12, it was working, but I think it stopped working when I installed KDE. I'm using Gnome 2.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking (ok, I understand that something used to work but no longer does, but what?). Please explain what `Ctrl+F2` is supposed to do. Check whether you do have Gnome 3 or not, we can't guess that for you. This kind of keyboard shortcuts are defined by the desktop environment, so if you replaced Gnome by KDE, you get the KDE shortcuts and not the Gnome ones. Oh, and please use capital letters and proper punctuation so we know where a sentence ends and the next one begins.

Comment: @Gilles `ctrl + f2`  is supposed to open the app launcher sir, sorry about the punctuation, I'll fix it now, i have both kde and gnome so, as far as i know, it should work when you are in gnome

Comment: Under Gnome, run the command `xev` in a terminal, then press `Ctrl+F2`. Does anything appear in the terminal when you press the `F2` key? P.S. I edited your question to remove irrelevant digressions. Please confirm that you are indeed running Gnome 2 (no matter what else you have installed).

Comment: @Gilles I re-installed mint coz i had so many problems